# Global job in GitHub Actions to handle failure?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a few jobs running as part of a workflow for my CI/CD, for example, `verify, build, deploy-stage, deploy-prod.`

If any of these steps fail, I do some generic things: `send notification on Slack,` `comment on the PR,` `add/remove labels.`

However, I cannot seem to figure out a way to have a global "failure" handler and so these 3 steps are copy pasted over and over again at the bottom of each individual `job`.

Is there a way to only *one* reference of these steps, and if any of the jobs fail, you then go and run it?

Comment: A job that depends on all other jobs, and runs on `if: failure()`? See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#example-of-failure